# responsive css sprite in carousel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, css-sprites, responsiveness

I am trying to improve the load time of my site by making all the images on my page into a sprite.  The thing is that all of my images are in multiple bootstrap carousels, and when I try to work on the responsiveness of my images the carousel area around the image doesnt change in relation to the part of the sprite I am trying to focus on (I can get it to change with vmax, just not correctly).

[this is how the carousel shows up at certain points when I drag the screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzajf.png)

Is there a more exact way to responsively change the carousel so that it only shows the part of the sprite I want?  (when I am in full screen the carousel takes up almost the entire screen but when on mobile size it is only about half the screen).  I feel like maybe I could go in and change the dimensions I want with @media only, but that could be painstaking and I dont even know for sure that it would work.  Is that my only option/would it even work?  I really am just looking for the easiest way to do this.  Thanks!

Comment: It's unusual to have to optimise images to the extent of using a sprite set, but if it's necessary, you'll need to actually show us the code you're using. Can you please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :)

Comment: I've been down that road before and I'm telling you...it's not worth it. you can use sprites for icons and such but not for large images.

Comment: i am currently trying to make a site with 30 images (14 of which are larger - approx 5 MB each) load faster.  would simply switching to godaddy from google appspot help, or should I somehow still use sprites?